# Can I insert the text/code outside the monaco editor? the browser seems forbidden this operation

Tags: monaco-editor

this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1050) have the same problem and solution, but i have no idea about this.
[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2xYI.png)

Comment: You need to actually ask a question here, and not in (the headline of) a GitHub issue. You are also either misusing GitHub as a support forum or SO as a bugtracker.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.